# mono-service stopped after reboot

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu-14.04, mono-service

I developed C# application using Mono Develop and deployed as mono-service on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. There are few problems which I don't understand:

1. I noticed that mono-service application stop running after system is rebooted and lock file not exists.
2. Also I noticed when I disconnect power of computer mono-service application stop running. Beside that, sometimes lock file exists even if mono-service application is stopped. Than when I read PID from file and try execute command "KILL pid" it said: "pid is not such a service"!
3. If is mono-service application stopped I noticed that I cannot remove any file and I received exception: "Permission denied". Probably because process still exists as Zombie.

**Now, my question is:** How I can properly maintain application which runs on mono-service? I mean how I can properly Start, Stop (without zombies) and ensure that service will runs always. Do I need to add some cron job to maintain this too?

I followed [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service) for for Start, Stop and Reset. 
This is how I start service:

```
mono-service -l:/root/app-lock /home/emc/appfolder/app.exe
```

Also I read [mattdeboard](http://mattdeboard.net/2012/10/19/how-to-run-windows-service-as-linux-daemon/) articles but I am still confused what is right way to keep service properly running.

Comment: As I can see , mono is not a popular thing here. That is sad because I have the same behaivor and problem

Comment: Definitely is not popular topic. I fixed this issue with Supervisor which is responsible to start, stop and restart service if is necessary. Anyway, it is solution but it is not entirely answer on my question.